# get the http post request body before jackson invocation in spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson, interceptor

i want to know is there a way to get the `HttpServletRequest` body before any `Jackson` involvement in spring. I tried it with `@JsonDeserializer` and spring `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` and also with a `HttpRequestWrapper` but no luck for now. if anyone knows please suggest me a way to do this thanks.

Comment: What is your use case, a small example of what you actually try to achieve would be nice

Comment: Try to add a custom filter/ servlel and grab the request.

Comment: Why can't you just use a servlet filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a custom `Filter` in the application (explained [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-filter)) and override `doFilter` method. E.g.:

```
public void doFilter(
      ServletRequest request, 
      ServletResponse response,
      FilterChain chain){
       ....
}
```

This would give you the `request` object from which, you can get the payload.

Comment: Yes, this is the way to go. Please, note that probably you'll need to use something like `org.springframework.web.util.ContentCachingRequestWrapper` to wrap your request, so that request body can be read again later by `Jackson`, for example